# Is there any way to get rEFInd or Mac Startup Manager to show up on an external display? Broken internal display on MacBook Pro 2016

Tags: display, startup

My internal display is cracked and does not work, I am dual booting Linux/MacOS on a 2016 MacBook Pro with rEFInd, the issue is I can't select any boot options as neither rEFInd nor Startup Manager show up on my external display, and neither rEFInd nor startup manager have text-to-speech (like recovery mode) that I can use to "see" what's on the screen.

I don't have an external keyboard/mouse, so I can't use clamshell mode. Is there any way to force output to external display?

Comment: Really the correct answer here is grab a mouse and keyboard and run in clamshell mode.  It's not like either one needs to be special.

Comment: @MarcWilson Would startup manager show up in clamshell mode? I dont want to buy a mouse/keyboard without being 100% certain :P

Comment: You do not need to see the screen to use rEFInd.

Comment: @DavidAnderson How else would you be able to select boot OS?

Comment: There are many differ ways to select the boot OS. One way would be to press 1 through 9 to launch the specified boot loader by number. See [Using Keyboard Shortcuts](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/using.html#keyboard).

Comment: @pavel_fyodorovich Buy?  You know no one at all who owns a computer?  Mice and keyboards are a standard.